How to get a list of available VS Code versions and their download links?
Seems MS has an API to retrieve data on VS Code versions, although couldn't find docs on all the endpoints. Be it this API or another, is there a way to get a list of available VS Code versions available for download and their download URLs?

I think they are asll listed on the Visual Studio Code site.

If I'm looking at the same ones, they all point to a "latest" link for different distros/archs, rather than a list of all prior versions

If you click the Updates link it lists them by date. But your question should really be directed to Microsoft.

you can use https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/releases/stable and then https://update.code.visualstudio.com/${version}/win32-x64-user/stable (example for Windows) to download them.
